# exception while using jackson and ormlite annotations together in one object

Tags: android, json, jackson, deserialization, ormlite

I am using **Jackson** library to parse json into object and using **ormlite** to store same objects to the sqlite db. Here is my model classes:

```
public class Site {
    private String uniqueId;
    private String name;
    private ForeignCollection<ContactDetails> items;

    @JsonProperty("contact_details")
    public void setContactDetails(ForeignCollection<ContactDetails> contact_details) {
        this.items = contact_details;
    }

    public List<ContactDetails> getContactDetails() {
        return new ArrayList<ContactDetails>(items);
    }

    public String getUniqueId() {
        return uniqueId;
    }
    @JsonProperty("unique_id")
    public void setUniqueId(String uniqueId) {
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and the ContactDetails class is:

```
public class ContactDetails {

    @JsonProperty("contact_detail_id")
    int getContactDetailId;
    @JsonProperty("cellphone_number")
    String getCellphoneNumber;
    @JsonProperty("email")
    String getEmail;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    String getName;
}
```

and my json is:

```
{
    "unique_id": "WDV000282",
    "name": "2XL - Diverse werken - Zeebrugge",

    "contact_details": [
        {
            "contact_detail_id": 20647,
            "cellphone_number": "123456",
            "email": "plabon@gmail.com",
            "name": "plabon",

        },
        {
            "contact_detail_id": 20648,
            "cellphone_number": "",
            "email": "modak@gmail.com",
            "name": "test",

        }
    ]
}
```

But when i execute readvalue:

```
Site test= objectMapper.readValue(json, Site.class);
```

i get following exception

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not find a deserializer for non-concrete Collection type [collection type; class com.j256.ormlite.dao.ForeignCollection, contains [simple type, class com.example.jacksonparsingtest.ContactDetails]]
```

I am not getting what is happening??Plz help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ForeignCollection is an interface, Jackson cannot instantiate a new Object of that kind. I would try to either annotate the field with [@JsonDeserialize(as=ConcreteSubclassOfForeignCollection.class)](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/), use a concrete subclass like [BaseForeignCollection](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/BaseForeignCollection.html) or use a simple list like in this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14920916/2021412.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue by using **Collection** instead of ForeignCollection. Jackson can parse Collection now.

Comment: This is basically the third suggestion of my answer …

Comment: Yes i have seen this now. Thanks i am accepting your answer. Withdraw your downvote.

Comment: I am facing another problem with inserting those data in db. I have opened a seperate thread for that. Can you please help me.

[here is the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175696/parsing-with-jackson-and-inserting-same-object-to-sqlite-using-ormlite-android)

Comment: Cannot undo the vote (until an edit is made) but will upvote your question for (over-)compensation.