# Parsing with jackson and inserting same object to sqlite using ormlite android

Tags: android, ormlite, foreign-collection

I am parsing json data using **Jackson** from api call and trying to insert the data in sqlite using **ormlite**. For this i am using same model class. 
Here is my model classes

```
public class Site {

@DatabaseField(generatedId=true,columnName="ID")
private int id;
@DatabaseField(columnName="NAME")
private String name;
@ForeignCollectionField(eager=true)
Collection<Visit> visits;
Site() {

}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
@JsonProperty("name")
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Collection<Visit> getVisits() {
    return visits;
}
@JsonProperty("visits")
public void setVisits(Collection<Visit> visits) {
    this.visits = visits;
}



}
```

Here is visit model class

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "VISIT")
public class Visit {

@DatabaseField(generatedId=true,columnName="ID")
private int id;
@DatabaseField(columnName="VISIT_DATE")
private Date visitDate;

@ForeignCollectionField(eager=false)
Collection<CheckListItem> checklistItems;
@DatabaseField(foreign=true,foreignAutoRefresh=true,columnName="FOREIGN_ID")
private Site site;

Visit(){}

public Site getSite() {
    return site;
}
public void setSite(Site site) {
    this.site = site;
}


public Date getVisitDate() {
    return visitDate;
}
@JsonProperty("date")
public void setVisitDate(Date visitDate) {
    this.visitDate = visitDate;
}

public Collection<CheckListItem> getChecklistItems() {
    return checklistItems;
}
@JsonProperty("checklist_items")
public void setChecklistItems(Collection<CheckListItem> checklistItems) {
    this.checklistItems = checklistItems;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


}
```

I can parse the json data to list of site objects by following:

List siteList = objectMapper.readValue(jp, new TypeReference>(){});

And this worked perfectly. Now i want to store all this data(list of Site objects) in the db by using ormlite(with eager foreignCollection). For this i am trying like this:

```
for each site in siteList

Collection<Visit> vTemp=site.getVisits();
Dao<Site, Integer> siteListDao=getHelper().getSiteListDao();
s.visits=siteListDao.getEmptyForeignCollection("visits");
siteListDao.create(site);
for(Visit v:vTemp)
s.contacts.add(v);
```

Its inserting the data to the SITE and VISIT table. BUt when i try to fetch data by queryForAll() function on SITE table it returns a foreignCollection object(site.getVisits()) but its size is 0 although i have set the eager=true.

I am asuming i have done something wrong with inserting. Please tell me what is the proper way of doing this insertion using same model class object.

Comment: Hi. Did you find an answer for this? I have the same problem.

Comment: Up! 
\Same question, did you find a solution ?

Comment: Why isn't the Site class annotated as a database table?